# How to get users data from Facebook using Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, facebook, xcode4

I'm doing an App and I want to allow users to register from Fb, so, I thought of getting name, email and gender from Facebook, but cannot find a way to fetch the data, if anyone could help.

Here's an example of my code:

```
// extract the id's for which we will request the profile
    NSArray *fbids = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"email",@"gender", nil];

    // create the connection object
    FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

    // for each fbid in the array, we create a request object to fetch
    // the profile, along with a handler to respond to the results of the request
    for (NSString *fbid in fbids) {

        // create a handler block to handle the results of the request for fbid's profile
        FBRequestHandler handler = 
        ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            // output the results of the request
            [self requestCompleted:connection forFbID:fbid result:result error:error];

        };

        // create the request object, using the fbid as the graph path
        // as an alternative the request* static methods of the FBRequest class could
        // be used to fetch common requests, such as /me and /me/friends
        FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                                      graphPath:fbid];

        // add the request to the connection object, if more than one request is added
        // the connection object will compose the requests as a batch request; whether or
        // not the request is a batch or a singleton, the handler behavior is the same,
        // allowing the application to be dynamic in regards to whether a single or multiple
        // requests are occuring
        [newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];
    }



// FBSample logic
```

// Report any results.  Invoked once for each request we make.
- (void)requestCompleted:(FBRequestConnection *)connection
                 forFbID:fbID
                  result:(id)result
                   error:(NSError *)error {

```
// not the completion we were looking for...
if (self.requestConnection &&
    connection != self.requestConnection) {
    return;
}

// clean this up, for posterity
self.requestConnection = nil;

NSString *nombre;
NSString *localizacion;
NSString *genero;
NSString *cumpleanyos;
NSString *email;

if (error) {
    // error contains details about why the request failed
    nombre = error.localizedDescription;
} else {
    // result is the json response from a successful request
    NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;
    // we pull the name property out, if there is one, and display it
    nombre = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    localizacion = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"location"];
    genero = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"gender"];
    cumpleanyos = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"birthday"];
    email = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"email"];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with:

```
NSArray *fbids = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"email",@"gender", nil];
```

You'll need to use "FaceBook User Ids" try with:

```
NSString *camposUsuario = @"4,6";
NSArray *fbids = [camposUsuario componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

In this case "4" and "6" are "FaceBook User Ids".

If you want Request information for a specific user you need to know his "FaceBook User Id".